# Unable to read the sensor data from all the sensors connected

Tags: sensors, multiplexer, distance

I am trying to build a project where I have connected 8 Sparkfun TOF Sensors to an I2C MUX which is connected to a Sparkfun RedBoard.

I need to read and display the data from each sensor on the serial monitor right now and later on an OLED Display. The issue I am facing is that it is reading data only from the first sensor and then it stops running.

I have pasted my code below. I am new to all of this so any help would be appreciated on how to fix this issue.  The `enableMux()` and `disableMux()` functions are from the GitHub example code libraries. I want to know if the issue is that I am not enabling my ports properly or if the issue is with my data reading. Do I need to initialize each sensor individually?

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
#include "SparkFun_TMF882X_Library.h" 

#define sensors 8
SparkFun_TMF882X  myTMF882X;




void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial);
  Wire.begin();
  for(byte x=0;x<sensors;x++)
  {
    enableMuxPort(x);
    if(!myTMF882X.begin())
    {
        Serial.println("Error - The TMF882X failed to initialize - is the board connected?");
        while(1);
    }
    else
    Serial.print(x+1);
    Serial.println(" TMF882X started.");
    disableMuxPort(x);
  }
}
 

void loop()
{
    delay(500);
    for(byte x=0;x<sensors;x++)
    {
      enableMuxPort(x);
      struct tmf882x_msg_meas_results myResults;
      
      myTMF882X.startMeasuring(myResults);
      Serial.print(myResults.num_results);
      unsigned int distance = myResults.results[0].distance_mm;
      Serial.print("Sensor ");
      Serial.print(x+1);
      Serial.print(" distance: ");
      Serial.print(distance);
      Serial.print("mm");
      Serial.println();
      disableMuxPort(x); 
    }
}
```

Hardware Used:

> Microcontroller: Sparkfun Redboard Turbo
> MUX: SparkFun Qwiic Mux Breakout - 8 Channel (TCA9548A) - BOB-16784 - SparkFun Electronics
> Sensor: Qwiic dToF Imager (TMF882X) Hookup Guide - SparkFun Learn

Below is the output I am getting:

```
1 TMF882X started.

2 TMF882X started.

3 TMF882X started.

4 TMF882X started.

5 TMF882X started.

6 TMF882X started.

7 TMF882X started.

8 TMF882X started.

9Sensor 1 distance: 3325mm

0Sensor 2 distance: 0mm
```

Comment: you have to supply the module I2C address when you instantiate the `SparkFun_TMF882X`  object

Comment: I'd have started with the assumption that you have to create 8 objects of type SparkFun_TMF882X as 
`SparkFun_TMF882X myTMF882X[ 8 ];` instead of using a shared object. Alternatively, call the begin() method each time you switch to a different sensor. You could also test the multiplexing by hardcoding say `enableMuxPort(2);` to see if it works  for just sensor 2.

Comment: Where is the definition of `enableMux(`) and `disableMux()`?